# I'm doing it when I get an error Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias can anyone help me why is it wrong?

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT a.telegram_name, a.full_name, a.role_id, a.user_id 
        from tbl_telegram_user a 
         LEFT JOIN ( 
        select a.owner_id, a.owner_name from tbl_agenda as a
        join ( 
         select a.type, a.message, a.status from tbl_message as a 
        join tbl_status as b 
        join (select * from tbl_agenda as a join tbl_message as b
         on a.type = b.type
         where a.type="/mom" and ( current_date BETWEEN from_time and to_time ) is not null)
        on a.status = b.status 
        where b.status_type = 'workLocation' or b.status_type = 'off') as b
     on a.type = b.type 
         where DATE(a.from_time) = DATE('2021-08-10 21:04:02')) as b 
         on a.telegram_name = b.owner_name 
         where b.owner_name is null AND a.user_id <> 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think in line 9 you forget alias :

```
SELECT a.telegram_name, a.full_name, a.role_id, a.user_id from tbl_telegram_user a LEFT JOIN ( select a.owner_id, a.owner_name from tbl_agenda as a join ( select a.type, a.message, a.status from tbl_message as a join tbl_status as b join (select * from tbl_agenda as a join tbl_message as b on a.type = b.type where a.type="/mom" and ( current_date BETWEEN from_time and to_time ) is not null) as "your alias" on a.status = b.status where b.status_type = 'workLocation' or b.status_type = 'off') as b on a.type = b.type where DATE(a.from_time) = DATE('2021-08-10 21:04:02')) as b on a.telegram_name = b.owner_name where b.owner_name is null AND a.user_id <> 0
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"your alias" on a.status = b.status where b.status_type = 'workLocation' or b.st' at line 1  that's the error i get when i run your command

Comment: now i want if between frontime to totime it will not return any result can anyone help me

Comment: i think i only tell you where you forget your alias that why i write "your alias" you have to enter your custom alias name whatever you like

Comment: i think  remove this line  DATE('2021-08-10 21:04:02')) and use this  '2021-08-10' just give it try maybe it will run

Comment: I tried it and it shows a red X =) probably not

Comment: can you please share sql fiddle link i have to try it.

Comment: Can you leave a link of a social network you are using so we can make friends and exchange

Comment: i think i  found one mistake in line 10 `current_date BETWEEN from_time and to_time` condition use `a.current_date BETWEEN from_time and to_time`.

Comment: no i tried and it doesn't work if i leave out the sentence from line 8 to 10 then both work normally if you are free can team view test my sql query

Comment: can you leave something on facebook and instagram and telegram so i can talk???

Answer (score 0):

Seems alias was missing to sub query. Try below query.

```
SELECT a.telegram_name, a.full_name, a.role_id, a.user_id 
            from tbl_telegram_user a 
             LEFT JOIN ( 
            select a.owner_id, a.owner_name from tbl_agenda as a
            join ( 
             select a.type, a.message, a.status from tbl_message as a 
            join tbl_status as b 
            join (select * from tbl_agenda as a join tbl_message as b
             on a.type = b.type
             where a.type="/mom" and ( current_date BETWEEN from_time and to_time ) is not null) as a
            on a.status = b.status 
            where b.status_type = 'workLocation' or b.status_type = 'off') as b
         on a.type = b.type 
             where DATE(a.from_time) = DATE('2021-08-10 21:04:02')) as b 
             on a.telegram_name = b.owner_name 
             where b.owner_name is null AND a.user_id <> 0
```

Comment: Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'type'

Comment: now i want if between frontime to totime it will not return any result can anyone help me